# Enable PhpMyAdmin’s Extra Features

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am encountering a problem enabling the extra features in phpmyadmin.

I have installed phpmyadmin (v 4.5.4.1) on a mac using homebrew with php (v 5.6.18) also installed via homebrew.

I added the `blowfish_secret` and created the `pma` user then imported the `create_tables.sql` file which was located in `/usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/sql`. There was no `create_tables.sql` file located in the `examples` or `scripts` folders.

I then ran the following sql commands:

```
GRANT USAGE ON mysql.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT (
Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv,
Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv,
File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv,
Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv,
Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv
) ON mysql.user TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT (Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv)
ON mysql.tables_priv TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON phpmyadmin.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Error
SQL query: Documentation


GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

I am not sure what I need to do, and searching hasn't helped me find a solution.

Comment: Could you please also post the output of `mysql --version`?

Comment: ```alisamii@alisamii  /  mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me as if your MySQL tables were not upgraded as part of an update from an older version. Normally MySQL provides a utility script to perform this, called `mysql_upgrade` which you can run from the command line. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html has more information on the details of using the command, but I've always just run `mysql_upgrade` without any other problems. Once you've upgraded the internal MySQL tables used for all user accounts, you should be able to compete the steps for phpMyAdmin.